# We have any support for the RestAPI testing in Playwright Java?

Tags: java, playwright

I don't see any documentation for the Rest API testing in Playwright JAVA. Could you please share if there is any support available?

Answer (score 1):

Based on this doc, you can do the API testing with Java:
https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api-testing
Please refer it.